# How to implement squid authentication for LAN

Tags: authentication, squid

I am doing my final year project using squid as my proxy server, i need to implement some secure way of authentication before anyone can have access to the internet. How do i go about that? I am using MySQL as my database, can I do it that way or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Authenticate/Mysql) describes how to setup mysql-based authentication with squid. It seems easy to follow.

Comment: @Gabriela: If you want to thank someone, you can accept his answer!